# I want to add data manually into multiple rows in my jtable. I'm working on netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

this is my code. what happens is when i select a record and click on a button that record is added to all the fields. Thus im not able to feed more than 1 row in my jtable. i want to enter the data and then change the row so that more data can be entered. i know i am doing something wrong, i just cant find it out.

```
public void gencode(String a1, String a2, String a3,String a4, String a5){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
       jTable1.setValueAt(a1, i, 0);
       jTable1.setValueAt(a2, i, 1);
       jTable1.setValueAt(a3, i, 2);
       jTable1.setValueAt(a4, i, 3);
       jTable1.setValueAt(a5, i, 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: because set value for column.did you follow a tutorial ??

Comment: If you put it in for loop that is what will happen.What else you expect from your code

Comment: then what changes should i do so that it feeds the value in only 1 row and then changes its column. ?

Comment: @AnmolKhanna how much rows your jtable have initially ?? do you want to add new rows with values ?or do you want to fill exsiting rows one by one?

Comment: @Fast Snail I have 15 rows in my table.
i want to manually fill these rows with data.
when i select a data row and press a button the data should get added to the table. but i can do it for only 1 row while i want to do it for multiple

Comment: @AnmolKhanna your code should work..clarify what's wrong

Comment: @FastSnail i know how to get the index, but how do i pass it properly ?

Comment: ok @AnmolKhanna first tell me from which values you want to fill the table

Comment: i have a frame1 from which i enter data and save it to a database.
i have another table in the first frame which shows all the data from my database. when i select a row from my table in frame1 and click on a button, the data is set to a table2 in another frame. till now things are working fine.
but if i want to add more than one row to the table in frame2, i am not able to do that

Comment: @AnmolKhanna ok but why this for loop?? you should declare this index variable as a instance variable not a local. and you remove the for loop.that's it

Comment: if i remove the for loop, i can indeed feed the data to the table. but when i select another row to feed in the table, the previous selected row gets replaced. @Fast Snail

Comment: @AnmolKhanna nope.how could it happen?? you send data from table to this table.right? this is your sub table right??this is example i'm taking about http://pastebin.com/EvZpm8H1  .you send values to this method it fill firstrow .and you again send data to this method and method  fill second row.so on

Comment: @Fast Snail that is the problem. it isnt filling the second row. my first row data gets replaced !

Comment: @AnmolKhanna if first row get replaced that mean `jTable1.setValueAt(a1, i, 0)`  `i ==0 ` which mean you create a index variable inside the `gencode()` method .or you don't increment it.did you at least try the code i posted in pastebin

Comment: @Fast Snail i tried exactly the same code. moreover, in your code, there are two diff variables i and index !

Comment: and changing it to only one variable, the same happens. my first row gets replaced

Comment: @AnmolKhanna oops i'm sorry about that .there shouldn't 2 variables ..only i know index .this is it http://pastebin.com/EvZpm8H1

Comment: @FastSnail nope. still the same problem

Comment: ok @AnmolKhanna upload a snap shot here http://imgur.com/ ,there is know way to replace first row

Comment: see @FastSnail http://anmolkhanna.imgur.com/all/?third_party=1

Comment: @AnmolKhanna  `AnmolKhanna's images are not publicly available. `. change privacy

Comment: @AnmolKhanna i see a error. may be you should fix it first

Comment: what error ? @FastSnail

Comment: @AnmolKhanna null pointer exception in output console

Comment: @FastSnail how do i fix it ?

Comment: @AnmolKhanna you should find where it occurs.i can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: @FastSnail Its showing me an error where there cant possibly be any error

Comment: @FastSnail the problem is, everytime i enter something into a table, a new frame opens up with its value at the 0th row

Comment: @AnmolKhanna could you post your all codes to pastebin.com ?then i can take a look

Comment: @FastSnail okay. give me a minute

Comment: @FastSnail http://pastebin.com/adyrUM5z